# Application closing immediately after pressing run

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have encountered a problem that When I run the application in
Visual Studio 2005 by pressing the Run button then VS IDE closes automatically without giving any error message.
But when I run without debugging with Ctrl+F5 then Application page runs sucessfully.

As a solution I have installed fresh copy of visual studio but the problem remains unchanged.

Comment: For some reason, the title made me laugh. :D

Comment: What kind of app are you writing? desktop/console/web? VB/C#/C++? winforms/wpf?

Comment: So many words, so little information. I'm tempted to close as "not a real question", but I know that he really does have a question in his head.

Comment: Oh, I remember good old days when I was working with VS2003 and Visual Assit installed. Once in a while, you just move your mouse across code window, assist would try to show you some clever tooltip and crash a VS during that. Silently. As it was never run. Just imagine, you are looking at code, one mouse movement and you're now looking at background image. Stunned. I learnt to move my mouse *around* windows with code at that job.

Comment: I vaguely remember things like that happening to me. taking a detour when moving the mouse.e that must have been fun! :P

Comment: I am confused. Does your app close immediately after you run? or does Visual Studio close?

Comment: Probably, the moment he runs his program in debug mode, his IDE crashes..!

Answer (score 1):

`Console` close immediately after running in **debug mode** if there's nothing to keep them open.

Try adding a `Console.ReadLine()` to the end of your program.

Answer (score 0):

you can debug release build also, just set the project configuration to Release and press the Debug button. Also in the project options, you can play with the various optimizations in Release mode, and can specify whether the Release build contains debugging information. The options depends on the type of the project which you haven't specified.

Comment: i will be surprised if he creates another config similar to the debug configuration and VS doesn't crash!

Answer (score 0):

**Seek professional help.**

Specifically, Microsoft's support offerings.

Start here: http://support.microsoft.com/oas

Answer (score 0):

What operating system?  Perhaps, you could check you debug settings and restore the defaults.

I have an application that crashes when pressing run, but only if I have unsaved changed.  I just compile before pressing run and then it all works fine.  This happens on windows 7 only and I haven't been able to pinpoint the problem, but the compile before run work-around works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Search (ctrl+shift+f for entire solution) for '#if DEBUG'. You may just be missing executing code due to a mistake. I've seen it happen to a person or three.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Event Viewer` for more information about the problem.